# Email file using grails export plugin

Tags: grails, export-to-excel

Currently I am using the export plugin to create an excel file on the fly on the server and then sending it to the browser via response.outputstream (done by the export plugin). Instead, what I want it to create the excel file and once done, email it to the user. Assuming I have the email can someone show me some sample code?

I looked into the export plugin code and it looks like it writes to the response output stream. Can I somehow read from this output stream, create a file, not store it to disc and just email it instead?

Answer (score 4):

Export plugin can create file in server as well.

```
File exportOutput = new File("/home/mkb/test.csv")
def exportOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(exportOutput)
exportService.export('csv', exportOutputStream, User.list(), fields, labels, formatters, parameters)
```

and once you got the file then you can easily email it using grails [mail plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/mail) as an attachment.

Comment: should be marked as the right answer. The export method only need the outupstream, it can be from httpresponse or from a File

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the `attach(String fileName, String contentType, InputStreamSource source)` method in the [Grails Mail](http://grails.org/plugin/mail) DSL.  This allows you to do everything in memory without writing a file to disc.

```
import org.springframework.core.io.ByteArrayResource
...

OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
exportService.export(type, outputStream, objects, fields, labels, formatters, parameters)
InputStreamSource inputStream = new ByteArrayResource(outputStream.bytes)  //copy output stream to input stream

sendMail {
   mutipart true
   to "someone@org.com"
   attach "yourfile.txt", "text/plain", inputStream
}
```

More info [here](http://gpc.github.io/grails-mail/docs/guide/3.%20Sending%20Email.html#3.3%20Attachments).

Hope that helps!